# В зенде 2 получаю ошибку при попытке вывода вида

Tags: php, layout, view, zend-framework-2

Как в зенде в один модуль несколько шаблонов указать?
Я делаю так но не пашет

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {   $this->layout('layout/layout');
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $menu = new ViewModel();
        $menu->setTemplate('application/menu');
        $view->addChild($menu, 'menu');
    return $view;
    }

    public function portfolioAction()
    {
        $this->layout('layout/portfolio');
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $menu = new ViewModel();
        $menu->setTemplate('application/menu');
        $view->addChild($menu, 'menu');
    return $view;
    }
}

    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/portfolio'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout_portfolio.phtml',
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),

   'module_layouts' => array(
      'Application' => array(
          'home' => 'layout/layout',
          'portfolio'    => 'layout/layout_portfolio',
        ),
    ),
),
```

У меня ошибка:

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "application/index/portfolio"; resolver could not resolve to a file